# Is there a convention for what is a row and what is a column?

Tags: c++, coding-style, naming-conventions

Consider a matrix build as a vector of vectors such as the following for example

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> M;
```

When indexing a value in such matrix, does it make more intuitive sense to most programmers when doing so as `M[row][column]`or `M[column][row]`?

Comment: I think this question is primarily opinion-based. That said, it seems the convention is row major order, i.e., M[r][c] or each row is contiguous in memory.

Comment: @Brian I would have though it fit perfectly in the tag `naming-conventions`. I would have though row first as well.

Comment: From a Mathematical perspective, it's mostly thought as `i-th` *row* and `j-th` *column*. I did like to believe most programmers including myself think that way too.... BTW, non of these matter when it comes to matrices with different access patterns where we may need to go column major

Comment: *what is better* is an opinion. What is most used isn't (if you can tell)

Comment: Definitely spaces, tabs can be a pain when editors differ. And I don't care if you own a compression company and multiple spaces is more data than a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to interpret this as you want:  the question is wether you see the outer vector M as a vector of lines or a vector of columns.   `M[i][j]`  would then mean the `j`-st item in the `i`-st vector in `M`.

Naturally, C++ programmers would tend to use `M[row][column]`.  This is because it corresponds the way the data is stored in memory when you define a 2D array. For example:

```
int M[2][3] = { { 11,12,13}, {21,22,23} };
```

would be stored in memory with elements of a row stored successively (like columns), and once the row is stored, store the next row:

```
11 12 13 21 22 23
```

or if you'd fix the width of the display:

```
11 12 13
21 22 23
```

Answer (score 1):

What matters is how you access the array. Sequential memory accesses are generally faster than non-sequential ones. So if you are running some algorithm on your array, and in its inner loop, the "row" is constant but the "column" is being iterated over, then you want column elements to be sequential in memory. In your case of a vector of vectors, that means you want the inner vector to be the "column", so you want to access it as `M[row][column]`.